# which event get fired when call does not get picked up?

Tags: asterisk-ari

In case of incoming call, call does not get picked then what will happen to ari channel and what event will get fired that call is disconnected?

Comment: I'm sure it's StasisEnd.

Answer (score 0):

Event after the disconnect is `StasisEnd`.
The channel will live forever by default and will be destroyed after the caller hang up.